# How can I check if an element of an array is the terminating element and return a new line?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to check an array like 'Hello' and check when the terminating element is and then return a new line due to it. I've been trying code like this:

```
char * my_strchr(const char * string, int ch)
{
  int count;
  int length = strlen(string);

  for(count = 0; count < length; count++)
  {
    if(string[count] == '\0')
    {
      return '\n' ;
    }
  }
```

My compiler does not like when I use these for some reason. In the function declaration for string it reads `const char * string`

Comment: When you say your "compiler does not like" this -- what is the actual error message?

Comment: return makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: `string[count] == '\0'` : It is not true under this condition of `count < length`. ?

Comment: Please show us the full function, as well as the definition of `length`.

Comment: So (guessing, since you haven't shown) your function is returning `char *` or `const char *`? If so, you'd return `"\n"`, but that seems pointless (although so does always returning `'\n'`).

Comment: My end goal is to create a function that does the same thing as the strchr() function.  One aspect of it is that if the inputed array only contains '\0' , a new line is printed as the output.

Comment: type of return of function my_strchr is `char *`. but '\n' is `int`. NULL is desirable that the return value if the specified character is not found.

Comment: Also **note** `string[count] == '\0'` will **always** occur at `string[length]` due to your use of `length = strlen(string);`. Since `count < length` is your loop counter, `string[count] == '\0'` will **never** be **true**.

Comment: The note above should read: will **always** occur at `string[length-1]`. As such you will match, but looping is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The `strlen` function returns the string length *without* the `NULL` terminator. What this means is that your function does not return a `char` pointer, because your code will never get to the condition `string[count] == '\0'`.

Further, even if you did reach that condition, you are returning a `char`, not a `char *`, which is an error. Your function agreed to return a `char *` so some kind of `char *` needs to be returned, even if it points to `NULL`.

It also isn't clear from your function code, because it lacks a terminating bracket, but your function may never return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of guessing from your description, but perhaps something like this?

```
char * my_strchr(const char * string, int ch) {

    int i;
    int c;

    for (i = 0; (c = string[i]) != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (c == ch) return string + i;           /* aka &string[i] */
    }
    return "\n";        /* got to the end w/o finding ch in string */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *my_strchr(const char *string, int ch){
    if(*string == '\0')
        putchar('\n');//side effect
    while(*string){
        if(*string == ch)
            return (char*)string;
        ++string;
    }
    return *string == ch ? (char*)string : NULL;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but does not explain the root cause if the OP's issue.